# i am using an ImageSlideshow in my flutter app but i need to add some icons on the slide. something like the image below?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

```
    Center(
            child: Container(
              height: height * 0.3,
              width: width * 0.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: ImageSlideshow(
                indicatorColor: HexColor('#FFA300'),
                onPageChanged: (value) {},
                autoPlayInterval: 3000,
                isLoop: true,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/sample1.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/sample2.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/board3.jpeg',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

1. this is code for the ImageSlideshow widget. I need assistance please?
2. the normal way was use a container in a container but this one seems off

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an image in your question, but taking a look at your code and assuming you're using the [flutter_image_slideshow](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_slideshow) package on pub.dev. You can display the images and an icon as part of one 'slide' using a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget.

Here's an example where the first slide has the Icon on top of the image, but the others don't demonstrating that the ImageSlideshow accepts any widgets as children.

```
return Center(
  child: Container(
    height: height * 0.3,
    width: width * 0.8,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    child: ImageSlideshow(
      indicatorColor: HexColor('#FFA300'),
      onPageChanged: (value) {},
      autoPlayInterval: 3000,
      isLoop: true,
      children: [
        Stack(children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/sample1.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          const Icon(Icons.star)
        ]),
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/sample2.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/board3.jpeg',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the ImageSlideshow widget with a Stack widget and used a Row in a Container then used alignment property to assign the position of the Row

```
Stack(
                children: [
                  ImageSlideshow(
                  indicatorColor: HexColor('#FFA300'),
                  onPageChanged: (value) {},
                  autoPlayInterval: 3000,
                  isLoop: true,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/sample1.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/sample2.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/board3.jpeg',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                        SizedBox(width: width * 0.5,),
                        Icon(Icons.ios_share),
                        Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              )
```

this should solve it